# Why my code fires bullet at random positions?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I see that the bullets are being fired at random positions and not actually in forward direction of the camera. What's wrong here and how should I fix it?
So I am using pooling and each time the bullet is enabled this code is run:

```
private void OnEnable()
     {
         transform.position = Camera.main.transform.position;
         transform.rotation =Quaternion.identity;
         GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce((Camera.main.transform.forward + new Vector3(0, 0, 0)) * 5000);
         Invoke("Destroy", 1.5f);
     }
```

I have also changed it to the below code but even the second one doesn't work.

```
 private void OnEnable()
     {
         Rigidbody rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
         rb.position = Camera.main.transform.position;
         rb.rotation = Quaternion.identity;
         rb.AddForce((Camera.main.transform.forward + new Vector3(0, 0, 0)) * 5000);
        Invoke("Destroy", 1.5f);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure the code works with out pooling. Secondly disable the collider component on the bullet (they might be colliding with themselves).

I've quickly tried this on my machine and this is the result I get.

[image]

```
using UnityEngine;

public class BulletController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    GameObject bulletPrefab;

    void Update()
    {
        GameObject bullet = Object.Instantiate(bulletPrefab);
        Rigidbody body = bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        body.position = Camera.main.transform.position;
        body.AddForce(Camera.main.transform.forward * 75f, ForceMode.Impulse);
    }
}
```

Comment: I always want the bullet to be shot in straight forward of camera and not like this. How should I correct this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I use with direction, position and velocity variables.

```
void Inception::shootGeode(std::string typeGeode, const btVector3& direction) {

    logStderr(VERBOSE, "MESSAGE: Shooting geode(s)...\n");

    std::shared_ptr<Geode> geode;

    glm::vec3 cameraPosition = m_camera->getPosition();
    btVector3 position = glm2bullet(cameraPosition + 3.0f * glm::normalize(m_camera->getTarget() - cameraPosition));

    if (typeGeode == "cube")
        geode = m_objectFactory->createCube("cube", new btBoxShape(btVector3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f)), position, "dice");

    if (typeGeode == "sphere")
        geode = m_objectFactory->createSphere("sphere", new btBoxShape(btVector3(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f)), position);

    btVector3 velocity = direction;
    velocity.normalize();
    velocity *= 25.0f;

    geode->getRigidBody()->setLinearVelocity(velocity);
}
```